# How to take last two maximum dates from multiple tables Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, maxdate

I have 4 tables and I am trying to get Last two maximum dates from these 4 tables. I have listed my query below:

```
WITH LAST_ATT_DATE AS 
        (
        SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,DATE AS LAST_DATE
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE NUM_REF='E1'
        UNION
        SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,DATE AS LAST_DATE
        FROM TABLE2
        WHERE NUM_REF='E1'
        UNION
        SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,DATE AS LAST_DATE
        FROM TABLE3
        WHERE NUMREF='E1'
        UNION
        SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,DATE AS LAST_DATE
        FROM TABLE4
        WHERE NUMREF='E1'
        )

        SELECT MAX(decode(RANK,1,LAST_DATE)),MAX(decode(RANK,2,LAST_DATE)) 
        FROM (SELECT NUMBER1,LAST_DATE,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY NUMBER1 
        ORDER BY LAST_DATE DESC) AS RANK 
        FROM LAST_ATT_DATE) WHERE RANK <= 2
        GROUP BY NUMBER1 ORDER BY NUMBER1;
```

For some records, it's working properly and for many records, it's showing the same date(only the first maximum date) even though it's having a 2nd maximum date.

Someone please correct this code or suggest any other alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood the question correctly. Please check below query.

```
    WITH LAST_ATT_DATE AS 
    (
    SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,DATE AS LAST_DATE
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE NUM_REF='E1'
    UNION
    SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,DATE AS LAST_DATE
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE NUM_REF='E1'
    UNION
    SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,DATE AS LAST_DATE
    FROM TABLE3
    WHERE NUMREF='E1'
    UNION
    SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,DATE AS LAST_DATE
    FROM TABLE4
    WHERE NUMREF='E1'
    )

    SELECT NUMBER1 , MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN LAST_DATE END) LAST_DATE_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN LAST_DATE END) LAST_DATE_2
    FROM (SELECT NUMBER1,LAST_DATE,Row_Number() OVER( 
    ORDER BY LAST_DATE DESC) AS RN 
    FROM LAST_ATT_DATE) WHERE RN <= 2
    GROUP BY NUMBER1 ORDER BY NUMBER1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`:

```
SELECT NUMBER1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN LAST_DATE END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN LAST_DATE) 
FROM (SELECT NUMBER1, LAST_DATE,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NUMBER1 
                                ORDER BY LAST_DATE DESC
                               ) AS seqnum 
      FROM LAST_ATT_DATE
     ) lad
     WHERE seqnum <= 2
GROUP BY NUMBER1
ORDER BY NUMBER1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your replies.

I got a solution to my question. I just truncated the date column and tried it's worked.

SELECT NUMREF AS NUMBER1,trunc(DATE) AS LAST_DATE
FROM TABLE1 WHERE NUMREF='E1';

Again thanks all.