# Oracle VIEW showing when last records were created in my tables

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have tables `t1` and `t2` and both of them do have columns `created_on` containing the timestamp when each record was created. Usual thing.

Now I'd like to create the view which would show my tables and the timestamp of last created record (`MAX(created_on)`) in corresponding table.

The result should look like:

```
table | last_record
======+============
t1    | 10.05.2019
t2    | 12.11.2020
```

For example I can retrieve the list of my tables with:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE table_name LIKE 'T%'
```

I'd like to get the timestamp of last record for each of these tables.

How to create this view?

Comment: I'd like to have the list of tables in some kind of list.

Comment: @MT0, why did you close that question? Did you read **everything** sbrbot wrote (comments included)? Nothing in a linked question answers this problem (at least, I didn't find it).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51413138/1509264

Comment: @Littlefoot Then find a better duplicate. I've linked another one and you can re-close it against that.

Comment: That's not it either, @MT0, I'm afraid. The OP has bunch of tables that contain the CREATED_ON column and wants to get list of all those tables and their MAX(CREATED_ON) column value **dynamically**. New tables might be created; old ones might be dropped - list of tables dynamically changes, and the *resulting query* should reflect all those changes. As of **finding a better duplicate**: nope, I won't be doing that, sorry.

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks, you understood my issue here.

Comment: So, did you try the last code I posted? Does it work?

Comment: @Littlefoot yes, thanks a lot, that's it. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: OK, no problem, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on tables' description; I presume they are somehow related to each other.

Anyway: here's how I understood the question. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  t1 (id, name, created_on) as
  4    (select 1, 'Little', date '2021-12-14' from dual union all  --> max for Little
  5     select 2, 'Foot'  , date '2021-12-13' from dual union all  --> max for Foot
  6     select 2, 'Foot'  , date '2021-12-10' from dual
  7    ),
  8  t2 (id, name, created_on) as
  9    (select 2, 'Foot'  , date '2021-12-09' from dual union all
 10     select 3, 'SBrbot', date '2021-12-14' from dual            --> max for SBrbot
 11    )
 12  -- query you'd use for a view
 13  select id, name, max(created_on) max_created_on
 14  from
 15     -- union them, so that it is easier to find max date
 16    (select id, name, created_on from t1
 17     union all
 18     select id, name, created_on from t2
 19    )
 20  group by id, name;

        ID NAME   MAX_CREATE
---------- ------ ----------
         1 Little 14.12.2021
         2 Foot   13.12.2021
         3 SBrbot 14.12.2021

SQL>
```

---

After you *fixed* the question, that's even easier; view query begins at line #12:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  t1 (id, name, created_on) as
  4    (select 1, 'Little', date '2021-12-14' from dual union all  
  5     select 2, 'Foot'  , date '2021-12-13' from dual union all  
  6     select 2, 'Foot'  , date '2021-12-10' from dual
  7    ),
  8  t2 (id, name, created_on) as
  9    (select 2, 'Foot'  , date '2021-12-09' from dual union all
 10     select 3, 'SBrbot', date '2021-12-14' from dual            
 11    )
 12  select 't1' source_table, max(created_on) max_created_on from t1
 13  union
 14  select 't2' source_table, max(created_on) max_created_on from t2;

SO MAX_CREATE
-- ----------
t1 14.12.2021
t2 14.12.2021

SQL>
```

---

If it has to be *dynamic*, one option is to create a function that returns ref cursor:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_max
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(4000);
  5    rc    sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select distinct c.table_name
  8                  from user_tab_columns c
  9                  where c.column_name = 'CREATED_ON'
 10                  order by c.table_name
 11                 )
 12    loop
 13      l_str := l_str ||' union all select ' || chr(39) || cur_r.table_name || chr(39) ||
 14                       ' table_name, max(created_on) last_updated from ' || cur_r.table_name;
 15    end loop;
 16
 17    l_str := ltrim(l_str, ' union all ');
 18
 19    open rc for l_str;
 20    return rc;
 21  end;
 22  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_max from dual;

F_MAX
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

TA LAST_UPDAT
-- ----------
T1 14.12.2021
T2 14.12.2021


SQL>
```

Comment: I changed my Q to make more clear how the result should look like. Tablenames should be in result.

Comment: That's even simpler. See the edited answer, please.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. I have 30+ tables and wanted avoid hard coding SELECT statements for each of these tables and UNION them all. I expected some solution where I would insert tablenames in kinda array and create JOIN to show result with all last records. I know problem is here that tablename is variable! DDL/DML

Comment: For example with query `SELECT * 
FROM USER_TABLES
WHERE table_name LIKE 'T%'` I can see my tables but I want to get what is the timestamp of last created record in each of these tables

Comment: It won't work that way; you'll need some kind of dynamic SQL. One option is to create a function that returns ref cursor (that's what I posted above; have a look).

Answer (score 1):

> I have 30+ tables and wanted avoid hard coding SELECT statements for each of these tables and UNION them all. I expected some solution where I would insert tablenames in kinda array and create JOIN to show result with all last records. I know problem is here that tablename is variable!

You cannot do this in SQL as a `VIEW` is set at compile time and the tables must be known; the best you can do is to dynamically create an SQL statement in PL/SQL and then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and then re-run it if you want to recreate the view:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_tables SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
    'TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'table3', 'TABLE5'
  );
  v_sql CLOB := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW last_dates (table_name, last_date) AS ';
BEGIN
  FOR i in 1 .. v_tables.COUNT LOOP
    IF i > 1 THEN
      v_sql := v_sql || ' UNION ALL ';
    END IF;
    v_sql := v_sql || 'SELECT '
                   || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(v_tables(i))
                   || ', MAX(created_on) FROM '
                   || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_tables(i), FALSE);
  END LOOP;
  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/
```

Then for the sample tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (created_on) AS
SELECT SYSDATE - LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE table2 (created_on) AS
SELECT SYSDATE - LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE "table3" (created_on) AS
SELECT SYSDATE - LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE table5 (created_on) AS
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

After running the PL/SQL block, then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM last_dates;
```

Outputs:

> | TABLE_NAME | LAST_DATE |
> | --- | --- |
> | TABLE1 | 2021-12-13 13:21:58 |
> | TABLE2 | 2021-12-13 13:21:59 |
> | table3 | 2021-12-13 13:21:59 |
> | TABLE5 | 2021-12-14 13:21:59 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=432cd0c1c33f0f4b5d810c7bb2f24010)*

Comment: thanks a lot, I appreciate your effort for quick response and specially in making fiddle example. Actually I just needed a solution or firm confirmation (which you gave us) that it is not possible to create VIEW with dynamic tablenames.